# Change crossfilter groups via a checkbox

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to build a visualisation to graph what I've been reading this year.

Currently I have everything grouped via Quantity of novels. I'm wondering if it's possible to change the group in real time or if I'm stuck with a group once I've set it.

The code that I've got now to calculate the groups looks something like this:

```
function groupByType(dimension){

  if($('#ValueType').is(':checked')) {
    console.log("Pages")
    return dimension.group()
            .reduceSum(function(d) {
              return d.Pages;
            });
  } else {
    console.log("Volumes");
    return dimension.group();
  }
}
```

Whenever the checkbox (#ValueType) is clicked I'm calling a dc.redraw on the entire graph which I was hoping would change the way the group is being calculated but it's not doing so. Is there way to change the group dynamically or would I be better off just refreshing the page and passing a parameter when it loads?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell, but it looks like every time you check or uncheck the checkbox, you create a new group. You do *not* want to do this as the groups stick around and continue getting updated. Things will just get slower and slower.

Just create the 2 groups upfront (and perhaps even 2 dc.js charts) and then let the checkbox control which group is assigned to the chart or which chart is displayed.